# How to find Grid view button click event?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
Button btnAddrecord = (Button)sender;
GridViewRow gvr =(GridViewRow)btnAddrecord.NamingContainer;
if (btnAddrecord.CommandName == "onAddMaterial")
```

Comment: kindly provide more details for the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the button in your grid view markup and assign a `CommandName` value to the button, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"  
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add Record">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddRecord"  
                            CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" 
                            CommandName="AddRecord" runat="server" Text="Add" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now in your code-behind, you can handle the `OnRowCommand` event and `AddRecord` command, like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "AddRecord")
    {
        // Get index of row passed as command argument
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, just curious how the "<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" syntax works.

Comment: @JoeManiaci - The `<%#` is called embedded code block syntax and in this particular variety of that syntax it is doing data-binding to the index (via the `RowIndex` property) of each row as it bound to the GridView control. Then when the user clicks the Add button in a particular row, the `CommandName` is used to  figure out what command the user wants to execute (there could be multiple commands in a single grid view row) and finally the `CommandArgument` is used to get the index of the exact row clicked by the user. This essentially allows you to get the context of the row the user clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1.Give a command name for button..
2.Then inside gridview

```
if e.commandname="yourcommandname"
{
//your code..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <!--We use onrowcommand for getting the selected row -->
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTest"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnRowCommand="gvTest_OnRowCommand" >
             <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BookId" >
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBookId" Text='<%# Bind("[BookId]") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBookId" Text='<%# Bind("[BookId]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete"  CommandArgument="<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>" CommandName="IsDelete" Text="Delete"></asp:Button>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

```
 //Code Behind

 protected void gvTest_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //getting rowindex which we have selected by using CommandArgument

                int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);


                    if (e.CommandName == "IsDelete")
                    {

                        int bkid = gvTest.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].FindControl("BookId");

                        //call a method to delete book using the bkid 

                    }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Response.Write(ex);
        }
    }
```