# Fetching Cell Value From GridView in Custom Method ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView with Template Fields and Connection String is located in the 
**web.config** File. Data is fetched by a stored procedure. I want to retrieve a single cell value of the Gridview in `protected void someMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)` on `OnClick="someMethod"` event. But it ends up with:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Code that generates the `OnClick` Event:

```
<asp:TemplateField >
           <ItemTemplate> 
           <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="someMethod">Get Name</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
```

The value of Gridview Cell i want to get is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="forNames" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="eForNames" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
```

And Code Behind is:

```
 protected void someMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 Label ename = diplayAdapter.SelectedRow.FindControl("eForNames") as Label;
            Label5.Text = ename.Text; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.ASPX Code:

```
<asp:TemplateField >
    <ItemTemplate> 
       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>" runat="server" CommandName="FindName">Get Name</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="forNames" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="eForNames" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

.CS Code

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //getting rowindex which we have selected by using CommandArgument
        int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        if (e.CommandName == "FindName")
        {
           Label5.Text= GridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].FindControl("eForNames");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kashif check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972987/how-to-find-grid-view-button-click-event

Comment: This philosophy is understandable. Thank You Sebu.

Comment: You are Welcome @Kashif